# Entity framework stored procedure call timeout

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

This is a strange one..

I have a stored procedure in my db which looks like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WITH CTE AS(

        --FC
        SELECT transno, RECHASEON,
            convert(varchar(12),orderdate, 101) as orderdate,
            convert(varchar(12),duedate, 101) as duedate,
            m.clientid+'-'+l.name as clientname,
            (SELECT TOP 1c.Comments FROM dbo.qcComments c WHERE m.transno = c.transno ORDER BY c.Comment_Date DESC) as MostRecentComment,
            'FC' as PortalType,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.qcComments c WHERE m.transno = c.transno) AS NumTimesKickedBack,
             m.SubRep,
             m.ClientID,
            (SELECT convert(varchar(12),MAX(c.Comment_Date), 101) FROM dbo.qcComments c WHERE m.transno = c.transno) as MostRecentReturnDate,
            (SELECT TOP 1 c.UserID FROM dbo.qcComments c WHERE m.transno = c.transno ORDER BY c.Comment_Date DESC) AS LastUserKickBack

        FROM dbo.maindata m (NOLOCK)
        inner join bluscreen.dbo.Lender L (NOLOCK) on L.clientid = M.clientid

        where m.cid = @CID  
        and ((@userlevel='SUBREP' and m.subrep=@UserName) or (@UserLevel<>'SUBREP'))
        and m.RCD=''    -- open assignment
        and exists (    -- qc kickback comments exist for the transno
            select transno 
            from dbo.qcComments c 
            where c.TransNo = m.TransNo)

        UNION

        --RPI
        SELECT  m.TransNo,
                m.RechaseON,
                convert(varchar(12),m.OrderDate, 101),
                convert(varchar(12),m.DueDate, 101),
                m.clientid+'-'+l.name as clientname,
                (SELECT TOP 1 c.message FROM rpi.dbo.msgbrd c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.msgtype= 'QC' ORDER BY c.datetime DESC) AS MostRecentComment,
                'RPI' as PortalType,
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rpi.dbo.msgbrd c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.msgtype= 'QC') as NumTimesKickedBack,
                m.SubRep,
                m.ClientID,
                (SELECT convert(varchar(12),MAX(c.datetime), 101) FROM rpi.dbo.msgbrd c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.msgtype= 'QC') as MostRecentReturnDate,
                (SELECT TOP 1 c.username FROM rpi.dbo.msgbrd c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.msgtype= 'QC' ORDER BY c.datetime DESC) AS LastUserKickBack

        FROM webdata.dbo.MainData m
        INNER JOIN  rpi.dbo.Requests r on m.TransNo=r.transno
        INNER JOIN bluscreen.dbo.Lender l on l.clientid = m.clientid
        INNER JOIN rpi.dbo.msgbrd msg on m.TransNo=msg.transno and msgtype='QC' --This join is used to check where a TransNo has been kicked back
        where m.RCD=''          --open
        AND r.qcpending='ON'    --qc kickback
        AND m.CID = @CID 
        and ((@userlevel='SUBREP' and m.subrep=@UserName) or (@UserLevel<>'SUBREP'))

        UNION 

        --LM
        select  m.TransNo,
                m.RechaseON,
                convert(varchar(12), m.OrderDate, 101),
                convert(varchar(12),m .DueDate, 101),
                m.clientid+'-'+l.name as clientname,
                (SELECT TOP 1 c.NOTES FROM LossMitigation.dbo.Translog_Call c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.CALL_RESULT_CODE = 'DIS' ORDER BY c.DATETIME_ENTRY DESC) as MostRecentComment,
                'LM' as PortalType,
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LossMitigation.dbo.Translog_Call c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.CALL_RESULT_CODE = 'DIS') as NumTimesKickedBack,
                m.SubRep,
                m.ClientID,
                (SELECT convert(varchar(12),MAX(c.DATETIME_ENTRY), 101) FROM LossMitigation.dbo.Translog_Call c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.CALL_RESULT_CODE = 'DIS') as MostRecentReturnDate,
                (SELECT TOP 1 c.USERID FROM LossMitigation.dbo.Translog_Call c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.CALL_RESULT_CODE = 'DIS' ORDER BY c.DATETIME_ENTRY DESC) as LastUserKickback

        from webdata.dbo.MainData m
        INNER JOIN lossmitigation.dbo.Requests r on m.TransNo=r.TRANSNO
        INNER JOIN lossmitigation.dbo.Translog_Call t on m.TransNo=t.TRANSNO and t.CALL_RESULT_CODE='DIS' --This join is used to check where a TransNo has been kicked back
        INNER JOIN bluscreen.dbo.Lender l on l.clientid = m.clientid
        where r.Status='PENDING' --open assignment
        AND m.CID = @CID 
        and ((@userlevel='SUBREP' and m.subrep=@UserName) or (@UserLevel<>'SUBREP'))
    )

    SELECT * FROM cte
    ORDER BY
            CASE
                WHEN @SortBy = 'Rechase' THEN RechaseON     
            END DESC,

            CASE
                WHEN @SortBy = 'NumKickbacks' THEN NumTimesKickedBack   
            END DESC,

            CASE 
                WHEN @SortBy = 'TransNo' THEN TransNo
                WHEN @SortBy = 'ClientID' THEN ClientName
                WHEN @SortBy = 'Subrep' THEN Subrep 
                WHEN @SortBy = 'LastKickbackUser' THEN LastUserKickBack

            END DESC,

            CASE 
                WHEN @SortBy = 'OrderDate' THEN OrderDate
                WHEN @SortBy = 'DueDate' THEN DueDate
                WHEN @SortBy = 'ReturnDate' THEN MostRecentReturnDate   
                ELSE TransNo    
            END ASC
```

In my code I have a call to the stored procedure using entity framework which looks like this:

```
using webDataDBContext = new WebDataEntities() {
var data = webDataDBContext.view_inqc_manifest_cid_II("11R", "REP", "rpfield", "TransNo").ToList()
}
```

If I run the stored procedure on the server it executes in less than a second. It runs this query:

```
 EXEC [dbo].[view_inqc_manifest_cid_II] '11R', 'REP', 'rpField', 'TransNo'
```

However the equivalent in .NET takes longer than 100 seconds to run(i cancel the query as it takes too long to run). I have absolutely no idea to why the .NET stored procedure call takes as long as it does, it's performing the exact same query.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Tables must have been getting locked?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
        WITH CTE AS(

            --FC
            SELECT transno, RECHASEON,
                convert(varchar(12),orderdate, 101) as orderdate,
                convert(varchar(12),duedate, 101) as duedate,
                m.clientid+'-'+l.name as clientname,
                (SELECT TOP 1c.Comments FROM dbo.qcComments c WHERE m.transno = c.transno ORDER BY c.Comment_Date DESC) as MostRecentComment,
                'FC' as PortalType,
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.qcComments c WHERE m.transno = c.transno) AS NumTimesKickedBack,
                 m.SubRep,
                 m.ClientID,
                (SELECT convert(varchar(12),MAX(c.Comment_Date), 101) FROM dbo.qcComments c WHERE m.transno = c.transno) as MostRecentReturnDate,
                (SELECT TOP 1 c.UserID FROM dbo.qcComments c WHERE m.transno = c.transno ORDER BY c.Comment_Date DESC) AS LastUserKickBack

            FROM dbo.maindata m (NOLOCK)
            inner join bluscreen.dbo.Lender L (NOLOCK) on L.clientid = M.clientid

            where m.cid = @CID  
            and ((@userlevel='SUBREP' and m.subrep=@UserName) or (@UserLevel<>'SUBREP'))
            and m.RCD=''    -- open assignment
            and exists (    -- qc kickback comments exist for the transno
                select transno 
                from dbo.qcComments c 
                where c.TransNo = m.TransNo)

            UNION

            --RPI
            SELECT  m.TransNo,
                    m.RechaseON,
                    convert(varchar(12),m.OrderDate, 101),
                    convert(varchar(12),m.DueDate, 101),
                    m.clientid+'-'+l.name as clientname,
                    (SELECT TOP 1 c.message FROM rpi.dbo.msgbrd c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.msgtype= 'QC' ORDER BY c.datetime DESC) AS MostRecentComment,
                    'RPI' as PortalType,
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rpi.dbo.msgbrd c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.msgtype= 'QC') as NumTimesKickedBack,
                    m.SubRep,
                    m.ClientID,
                    (SELECT convert(varchar(12),MAX(c.datetime), 101) FROM rpi.dbo.msgbrd c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.msgtype= 'QC') as MostRecentReturnDate,
                    (SELECT TOP 1 c.username FROM rpi.dbo.msgbrd c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.msgtype= 'QC' ORDER BY c.datetime DESC) AS LastUserKickBack

            FROM webdata.dbo.MainData m (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN  rpi.dbo.Requests r (NOLOCK) on m.TransNo=r.transno
            INNER JOIN bluscreen.dbo.Lender l (NOLOCK) on l.clientid = m.clientid
            INNER JOIN rpi.dbo.msgbrd msg (NOLOCK) on m.TransNo=msg.transno and msgtype='QC' --This join is used to check where a TransNo has been kicked back
            where m.RCD=''          --open
            AND r.qcpending='ON'    --qc kickback
            AND m.CID = @CID 
            and ((@userlevel='SUBREP' and m.subrep=@UserName) or (@UserLevel<>'SUBREP'))

            UNION 

            --LM
            select  m.TransNo,
                    m.RechaseON,
                    convert(varchar(12), m.OrderDate, 101),
                    convert(varchar(12),m .DueDate, 101),
                    m.clientid+'-'+l.name as clientname,
                    (SELECT TOP 1 c.NOTES FROM LossMitigation.dbo.Translog_Call c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.CALL_RESULT_CODE = 'DIS' ORDER BY c.DATETIME_ENTRY DESC) as MostRecentComment,
                    'LM' as PortalType,
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LossMitigation.dbo.Translog_Call c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.CALL_RESULT_CODE = 'DIS') as NumTimesKickedBack,
                    m.SubRep,
                    m.ClientID,
                    (SELECT convert(varchar(12),MAX(c.DATETIME_ENTRY), 101) FROM LossMitigation.dbo.Translog_Call c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.CALL_RESULT_CODE = 'DIS') as MostRecentReturnDate,
                    (SELECT TOP 1 c.USERID FROM LossMitigation.dbo.Translog_Call c WHERE m.transno = c.transno and c.CALL_RESULT_CODE = 'DIS' ORDER BY c.DATETIME_ENTRY DESC) as LastUserKickback

            from webdata.dbo.MainData m (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN lossmitigation.dbo.Requests r (NOLOCK) on m.TransNo=r.TRANSNO
            INNER JOIN lossmitigation.dbo.Translog_Call t (NOLOCK) on m.TransNo=t.TRANSNO and t.CALL_RESULT_CODE='DIS' --This join is used to check where a TransNo has been kicked back
            INNER JOIN bluscreen.dbo.Lender l (NOLOCK) on l.clientid = m.clientid
            where r.Status='PENDING' --open assignment
            AND m.CID = @CID 
            and ((@userlevel='SUBREP' and m.subrep=@UserName) or (@UserLevel<>'SUBREP'))
        )

        SELECT * FROM cte
        ORDER BY
                CASE
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'Rechase' THEN RechaseON     
                END DESC,

                CASE
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'NumKickbacks' THEN NumTimesKickedBack   
                END DESC,

                CASE 
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'TransNo' THEN TransNo
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'ClientID' THEN ClientName
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'Subrep' THEN Subrep 
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'LastKickbackUser' THEN LastUserKickBack

                END DESC,

                CASE 
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'OrderDate' THEN OrderDate
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'DueDate' THEN DueDate
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'ReturnDate' THEN MostRecentReturnDate   
                    ELSE TransNo    
                END ASC
```

I added no lock to the tables and it worked, strange as it works in the legacy version of the site... Must have something to do with entity framework